# Querying cyclic embeds_one associations in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Trying to query through an embedded_one association. I have a class `Person` that is **created_by** another `Person`. My research got me down to the following:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String

  embeds_one :created_by, class_name: self.name, cyclic: true
  embedded_in :created_person, class_name: self.name, cyclic: true
end
```

However, when I try to query or set `created_by` via the Rails console I am obtaining an error message. Can someone give me a hint on this? Much appreciated.

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 > a = Person.create!(first_name: "Marco", last_name:"Reus")
ruby 2.0.0p451 > a.created_by = a.id (error => NoMethodError: undefined method `__metadata' for BSON::ObjectId('5398b93e54686912b4000000'):BSON::ObjectId)
```